# Selenium findElementsBy.Xpath not finding all the elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Using Java and Selenium.

I am parsing a table.  Looks like the attached picture (I had to black out a couple confidential test items).

I get the row (“//table[@id=’proposalLineItemTable’]/tbody/tr”) which it finds.  I verify by looking at the id which is “tr1”.
Then I do a row.findElements(By.xpath(“td”)) and it finds only 1 element (class=”leftBorderSelected”).  The same is true with row.findElements(By.xpath(“./td”)).

I have to do a row.findElements(By.xpath(“.//td”)) to get them all, which is fine as long as there are no td//td elements.
But shouldn’t it find all the tds at the top level of the row?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML in (Firefox|Chrome) Dev Tools (Elements tabs).

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Comment: Also, add a tag for the programming language you are using... looks like Java?

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual code, we'd be guessing as to why your code isn't working. Given the HTML you've provided you can use a CSS selector

```
#tr1 td
```

to find all the TDs under the TR.

Make sure you are using a `WebDriverWait` to wait for all the TDs to be visible to ensure the table is fully loaded.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
List<WebElement> cells = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#tr1 td")));
```

Comment: It's just I have used this same method on other tables for several years and it has always worked.  I will try the css selector.

Comment: I found the problem.  Though it did not show up when I saw, the TD under the TR has a LABEL around it.  That is, inside the LABEL tag are most of the TD tags.  That seems a strange thing to do.